# Stopping event propagation in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a parent and child component. The child component, in my case, `<Person/>` has a wrapper `div` and `input` element. I have a click event for the `div` and change event for the `input` configured.

I need the click event to delete the person, whereas when I type in the input, it should update the name. For some reason, both the events are fired when i start typing in the input field. I tried cancelling the event using `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` but does not work. Any help would be appreaciated.

Please find the below demo code.

```js
(function () {
    class Person extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div onClick={this.props.onClickParent}>
                    <h1>{this.props.name} : {this.props.age}</h1>
                    <input
                        value={this.name}
                        onChange={this.props.onNameChange}
                        onFocus={
                            ev => {
                                ev.preventDefault();
                                ev.stopPropagation();
                                ev.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                ev.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
                                ev.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
                                this.props.onNameChange();
                            }
                        }
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {

        state = {
            people: [{
                age: 36,
                id: 1,
                name: 'Jon'
            }, {
                age: 28,
                id: 2,
                name: 'Bob'
            }],
        }

        onNameChange() {
            console.log('onNameChange')
        }

        onClickParent() {
            console.log('onClickParent')
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.people.map(person => {
                            return (
                                <Person
                                    name={person.name}
                                    age={person.age}
                                    key={person.id}
                                    onClickParent={this.onClickParent}
                                    onNameChange={this.onNameChange}
                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should just have to stop propagation in the `onClick` hander of the input element. Does this work as intended?

```js
(function () {
    class Person extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div onClick={this.props.onClickParent}>
                    <h1>{this.props.name} : {this.props.age}</h1>
                    <input
                        value={this.name}
                        onChange={this.props.onNameChange}
                        onClick={e => {
                          e.stopPropagation()
                        }}
                        onFocus={
                            ev => {
                                this.props.onNameChange();
                            }
                        }
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {

        state = {
            people: [{
                age: 36,
                id: 1,
                name: 'Jon'
            }, {
                age: 28,
                id: 2,
                name: 'Bob'
            }],
        }

        onNameChange() {
            console.log('onNameChange')
        }

        onClickParent() {
            console.log('onClickParent')
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.people.map(person => {
                            return (
                                <Person
                                    name={person.name}
                                    age={person.age}
                                    key={person.id}
                                    onClickParent={this.onClickParent}
                                    onNameChange={this.onNameChange}
                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping event propagation will work only for the same event. In your case - the `onClick` event.

You can add a new `onClick` event on the `input` element and stop the propagation there:

```js
(function () {
    class Person extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div onClick={this.props.onClickParent}>
                    <h1>{this.props.name} : {this.props.age}</h1>
                    <input
                        value={this.name}
                        onChange={this.props.onNameChange}
                        onClick={e=>e.stopPropagation()}
                        onFocus={
                            ev => {
                                ev.preventDefault();
                                ev.stopPropagation();
                                ev.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                ev.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
                                ev.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
                                this.props.onNameChange();
                            }
                        }
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {

        state = {
            people: [{
                age: 36,
                id: 1,
                name: 'Jon'
            }, {
                age: 28,
                id: 2,
                name: 'Bob'
            }],
        }

        onNameChange() {
            console.log('onNameChange')
        }

        onClickParent() {
            console.log('onClickParent')
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.people.map(person => {
                            return (
                                <Person
                                    name={person.name}
                                    age={person.age}
                                    key={person.id}
                                    onClickParent={this.onClickParent}
                                    onNameChange={this.onNameChange}
                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to check the target (if you don't want to add an extra handler for your input).

```js
  onClickParent(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "INPUT") {
      console.log("onClickParent");
    }
  }
```

Also you can simply have your input outside of your div. (you might have your reasons for putting it inside.... just wanted to mention this...)